# sql how to cast a select query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to apply the cast function to a select statement? If yes, how? I have a query that returns a number which I have to use a string to get other info's from another table.

Comment: Which Database System? SQL SERVER, MySQL etc..

Comment: Excellent question. Short and to the point. Enough information to get a reasonable answer - even without the specifics of the particular database server, or whether you are asking about SQL (which would be a reasonable assumption here). Just what I was looking for.

Comment: If gives error while using with ORDER BY CAST(`fieldname` as INT)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You just `CAST()` this way

```
SELECT cast(yourNumber as varchar(10))
FROM yourTable
```

Then if you want to `JOIN` based on it, you can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourOtherTable t2
    on cast(t1.yourNumber as varchar(10)) = t2.yourString
```

Comment: it gives error while using with ORDER BY CAST(fieldname as INT)

Comment: @VipulHadiya If you have a new question, then [ask one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @blufeet No, i got solution. CAST always gives me error, but if i use (columnName*1) it converts string to float that is what i wanted :)

Comment: Congrats this also works for spark SelectExpression method on dataframes.
df.selectExpr("colA", "colB as newName", "cast(colC as int)")

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can do.

Syntax for `CAST`:

```
CAST ( expression AS data_type [ ( length ) ] )
```

For example:

```
CAST(MyColumn AS Varchar(10))
```

`CAST` in `SELECT` Statement:

```
Select CAST(MyColumn AS Varchar(10)) AS MyColumn
FROM MyTable
```

See for more information [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: Though the question stated SQL Server 2008, I attempted simalar transactions in mysql, only to find varchar is invalid datatype for cast for mysql see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15368838/1815624

Answer (score 2):

I interpreted the question as using cast on a subquery.  Yes, you can do that:

```
select cast((<subquery>) as <newtype>)
```

If you do so, then you need to be sure that the  returns one row and one value.  And, since it returns one value, you could put the cast in the subquery instead:

```
select (select cast(<val> as <newtype>) . . .)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL (which you didn't say):

```
select cast(column as varchar(200)) from table
```

You can use it in any statement, for example:

```
select value where othervalue in( select cast(column as varchar(200)) from table)
from othertable
```

If you want to do a join query, the answer is here already in another post :)

Answer (score 0):

And when you use a case :

```
CASE
WHEN TB1.COD IS NULL THEN
    TB1.COD || ' - ' || TB1.NAME
ELSE
    TB1.COD || ' - ' || TB1.NAME || ' - ' || TB.NM_TABELAFRETE
END AS NR_FRETE,
```

Comment: SQL-Server does not support concatenation per "||"