# Joining tables MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

If I have the following tables

tbl1:

```
+------+-----------+
| sex  | type      |
+------+-----------+
|  m   | rolls     |
|  f   | acom      |
+------+-----------+
```

tbl2:

```
+------+-----------+
| age  | type      |
+------+-----------+
| 12   | rolls     |
| 25   | acom      |
+------+-----------+
```

How do I create a view to show the two tables merged but, sex and age become category

```
+-----------+-----------+
| category  | type      |
+-----------+-----------+
|    m      | rolls     |
|    f      | acom      |
|   12      | rolls     |
|   25      | acom      |
+-----------+-----------+
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `union` statement

```
SELECT `sex` as `category`,`type` FROM `tbl1`
UNION
SELECT `age` as `category`,`type` FROM `tbl2`
```

Comment: THAAAAAANKS, it work perfectly. It's there a way to change the Type of categorie to VARCHAR?

Answer (score 0):

you can that by using a union

```
select sex as category, type from tbl1
union
select age as category, type from tbl2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Union all merge two tables http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

```
select sex as category, type from table1
union all
select age as category, type from table2
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to [CAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) and then do UNION so that columns can have same datatype, like this:

```
CREATE VIEW `view1` AS
SELECT CAST(`sex` as CHAR(50)) AS `category`, `type` FROM `tbl1`
UNION
SELECT CAST(`age` as CHAR(50)) AS `category`, `type` FROM `tbl2`;
```

> In some earlier versions of MySQL, only the type and length from the first SELECT would have been used. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: It's there a way to change the Type of categorie to VARCHAR?
I tried:
SELECT CAST(`sex` as VARCHAR(10)) AS `category`, `type` FROM `tbl1`
But throws an error

Comment: @user2611352 No, it cannot be converted to VARCHAR. Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15368852/

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
create view v1 as 
select cast(sex as char(10)) as category, type from tbl1
union
select cast(age as char(10)) as category, type from tbl2
;
```

### **[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/862e7/1)**

```
| CATEGORY |  TYPE |
|----------|-------|
|        m | rolls |
|        f |  acom |
|       12 | rolls |
|       25 |  acom |
```