# Is it possible to cast the type of a column while using "SELECT *"?

Tags: sql, mysql

This is my table:

```
id| name  | address | more_info
_______________________________
0 | John  | NY      | infoa
1 | Bill  | PH      | infob
2 | Bob   | KS      | infoc
```

Where `id` type is `BIGINT`.

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
```

BIGINT is too long for some applications, thus I want to retrieve the `id` as a `VARCHAR`. Can I cast the `id` to `VARCHAR` in the result set without having to name each specific column I want to retrieve in the result set? I.E, I want to keep the actual query `SELECT *`, and not have to put `SELECT id, name, address` etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cast int to varchar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368753/cast-int-to-varchar)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple answer: no. 
You need some transformation stage/layer between your table and your expected result. You could have it with a view that casts integers to varchars, but since you are reluctant to introduce the coupling into `select`, I bet the view would be even worse.

On the other hand, there might be a chance on the app side, depending on the language.

*edit:*
If you can live having one additional column and one to ignore (the original id), maybe this would help:

```
select CAST(id as CHAR(50)) as idAsVarchar, t.* FROM
(
    select * from your_table
) as t;
```

Comment: I don't mind introducing coupling (I think), I just don't want to name each column I want extract except for the cast column, because I have around 40. Is this achievable?

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! But I had to add `as t` at the end of the query for it work ;) Consider editing your answer.

Comment: The subquery is redundant `SELECT *, CAST(id AS CHAR(50)) AS idAsVarChar FROM your_table` works also

Comment: Actually, when I look at my answer, it is pretty damn obvious. Good point!