# The json result of my php file contains ints but I need all the values as Strings

Tags: php, mysql, json

my json result from the mysqlquery in the php-file looks something like this: `[{"ID":1,"comment":"Hello"},{"ID":2,"comment":"SecondHello"}]`
For my purpose I need the IDs also as a String. 
I cannot/do not want to change the datatype in the database.
What do I have to change in my php file or in the Sql query to get the ID as a String.

```
 <?php
     $host = '';
     $db   = '';
     $user = '';
     $pass = '';
     $charset = 'utf8mb4';

     $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
     $opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
     ];
     $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);


     $sql= SELECT * FROM orders

     $resultArray = array();
     $tempArray = array();
     foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
      }
     echo json_encode($resultArray);
    ?>`
```

Comment: Cast to string is `(string)$value`

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368753/cast-int-to-varchar

Comment: you can use strval too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make sure that each row as you add it in is converted using `strval`...

```
 foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
    $tempArray = array_map('strval', $row);    // Convert all columns to strings
    array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
  }
```

Adds an overhead as this is applied to all columns, but it saves individual column by column processing (especially when the SQL changes)

Comment: Thank you very very much! This saved me sooo much time! Have a nice day and merry Christmas!

Answer (score 1):

what about this piece of code

```
$resultArray = array();
$tempArray = array();
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
    $fields = json_decode($row["jsonFieldName"],1);//decode your json string
    foreach($fields as $key=>$field){// read each object..
      $field["ID"] = strval($field["ID"]);// change the id property to str
      $fields[$key] = $field;// update decoded array
    }
    $row["jsonFieldName"] = json_encode($fields);//encode array and update value
    array_push($row, $row);
```

}

It may help you, but it is not a good way to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_map` to crawl your array and cast each element to string with `strval`

```
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
    $tempArray = array_map('strval', $row);
    array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
}
```