# SQL in Terminal Error: mismatched input ')' expecting ( near 'VARCHAR' in primitive type specification

Tags: mysql, sql

I am receiving the following error in Terminal when copy/pasting code from my code editor to Terminal:

> `mismatched input ')' expecting ( near 'VARCHAR' in primitive type specification`

Here is the SQL code in question:

```
left outer join order_history b
ON CAST(substr(a.order_id__c, 2)AS VARCHAR) = CAST(b.order_id AS VARCHAR)
```

The reason I am using the "substr" clause is because there is a letter in front of the number I am trying to join with in one table:

e.g. `P123456` and `123456`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cast int to varchar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368753/cast-int-to-varchar)

Answer (score 2):

VARCHAR can be used in a CAST.

The error is because the length of VARCHAR isnt mentioned.