# Conversion failed when converting the var char value '10, 11, 12, 60, 61, 111, 143, 144' to data type int

Tags: mysql, asp.net

Conversion failed when converting the var char value '10, 11, 12, 60, 61, 111, 143, 144' to data type int.

`Master Details` is var char contains 'list user, add user,list master,add master' value
and ID as int, User Access column is Var char containing '10, 11, 12, 60, 61, 111, 143, 144' value

```
Select Master Details 
from Master information 
where ID IN (SELECT User Access 
             FROM User Access Details where User ID = 22)
```

Comment: You are violating rules of 1NF in your database design - and you should try to not do that. Every field in a database should carry an atomic Information.

Comment: i used cast function as                                        Select ID,MasterDetails from Masterinformation where CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(15)) IN (select CAST(UserAccess AS VARCHAR(15)) FROM UserAccessDetails where UserID = 22)

Comment: You really should feel bad about that "solution". And btw.. 11 is in 114857 - that might be a Problem sometime...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have same column type in both your tables.
Otherwise use `cast` or `convert` to make it of same type in your query.

also you should use single column in you inner query or use `[]` for column name having spaces in your column name.

```
SELECT [User Access] 
         FROM User Access Details where User ID = 22
```

MSDN link for [cast and convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Some links

1. [sql how to cast a select query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989465/sql-how-to-cast-a-select-query)